# Can't access DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

I wrote a web application with a body onload event. I know this isn't optimal so I want to use DOMContentLoaded to trigger my init event.

I have a strange problem, I can't access my DOM element and I don't know why :/.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// add event listener
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

function init () {
    // pop up
    alert(document.getElementById(test).innerHTML);
}
```

Does somebody see the problem?

Comment: How about the generic `window.onload=init` or is it just your test that needs to be quoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add double quotes around test i.e. "test"

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

function init () {
    // pop up
    alert(document.getElementById("test").innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the undefined *variable* `test` to the `getElementById()` function, instead of the *string* value `'test'`.

So

```
document.getElementById(test); // Incorrect - as an undefined varible
```

Should in fact be

```
document.getElementById('test') // Correct - as a string value
```

Or

```
var element_id = 'test';
document.getElementById(element_id) // Correct - as a defined variable
```

Answer (score 2):

If your init function is executed, then you might add quote arroud your id :

```
document.getElementById(test)
```

becomes

```
document.getElementById('test')
```